# Fill in column if NULL with data from next column that is NOT NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Say I have the following table with a unique ID and 4 attribute columns...

```
|ID|  |Attribute 1|  |Attribute 2|  |Attribute 3|  |Attribute 4|
1          RED            NULL           BLUE          GREEN
2          NULL           BLUE           GREEN         NULL
3          GREEN          YELLOW         NULL          BLUE
4          YELLOW         NULL           NULL          GREEN
```

What can I use in SQL Server 2014 to say: If attribute 1 is NULL, use attribute 2, but if attribute 2 is NULL use Attribute 3, and so on... I was going to use a CASE statement, but I'm not sure how to go about it beyond CASE WHEN Attribute 1 IS NULL THEN Attribute 2, but then what if attribute 2 is NULL? How would I then select the next column value that is not NULL?

I want to somehow get the above, to this...

```
|ID|  |Attribute 1|  |Attribute 2|  |Attribute 3|  |Attribute 4|
1          RED            BLUE           GREEN        NULL
2          BLUE           GREEN          NULL         NULL
3          GREEN          YELLOW         BLUE         NULL
4          YELLOW         GREEN          NULL         NULL
```

Comment: Consider re-design you table: (id, attrno, color).

Answer (score 2):

This is a pain, but in SQL Server, you can use `outer apply` and some additional logic:

```
select t.id,
       v.attribute1, v.attribute2, v.attribute3, v.attribute4
from t outer apply
     (select max(case when seqnum = 1 then a end) as attribute1,
             max(case when seqnum = 2 then a end) as attribute2,
             max(case when seqnum = 3 then a end) as attribute3,
             max(case when seqnum = 4 then a end) as attribute4             
      from (select v.*, row_number() over (order by n) as seqnum
            from (values (1, t.attribute1), (2, attribute2), (3, t.attribute3), (4, t.attribute4)
                 ) v(n, a)
            where a is not null
           ) v
      ) v;
```

This unpivots the data and then repivots the values.

Comment: For some reason the CASE statements are not accepting the column value a. I am getting the "Invalid column name 'a'" error.

Comment: @OhioMike1987 . . . Ooops, there should have been an `a.*` in that subselect.

Answer (score 0):

`isNull` gets two parameters: an expression and a fallback. You need to use a combination of `isNull` calls:

```
isNull(attribute1, isNull(attribute2, isNull(attribute3, attribute4)))
```

[Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx).